# Why is ServletConfig obj passed to init() of GenericServlet when the class implements the interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

`GenericServlet` implements `ServletConfig` interface which means all the interface functions can be invoked from `init()` function of `GenericServlet`. Given this context, why does the Servlet container sends `ServletConfig` object to `init()` method? I would also like to know if the `ServletConfig` object that is passed to `GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig)` different from GenericServlet object.

Regards, 
Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GenericServlet` implements the `ServletConfig` methods by simply delegating to the config object passed to the init method. So it implements `ServletConfig` simply for convenience - it then simply delegates. So instead of calling `getServletConfig().getInitParameter()` you can call `getInitParameter()`

Comment: Thanks Bozho.  If a GenericServlet implements ServletConfig, typically there would be a consumer who knows GenericServlet only as a ServletConfig object.  Since servlet developers don't look at GenericServlet objects as ServletConfig objects, I assumed that some Servlet Container module has a ServletConfig reference to GenericServlet.  Is any part of my presumptions valid?

Comment: the servlet container has another implementation of ServletConfig which is the actual implementation used. it just passes it to the generic servlet